# How to avoid setting focus when showing multiple forms?

Tags: delphi, focus

First of all, this question is continued off of an answer of mine on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308843/invalidating-desktop-window-for-drawing-frame-around-a-window)...

Assume I'm using this particular solution to place a frame around any given window. How can I make this to where the focused form keeps its focus without jumping focus to these frame forms? Currently, i'd have to call `SetFocus` to set anything straight, but, then the windows get glitchy and don't show right.

How can I make sure the focused form keeps its focus at all times regardless of these 4 border forms showing?

Comment: Instead of creating 4 different forms for each side, why don't you simply create one border-less form whos clientRect is inflated over the Main App and simply control the z-index of that borderless form to position it behind the application thus giving the appearance of the 4 borders.

Comment: Your windows are getting glitchy because you're calling `SetFocus` during a focus-changing event. Wait until after all focus-change notification messages have passed before you try changing the focus, usually by posting another notification to yourself in the kill-focus message, and then calling `SetFocus` when you handle that other message later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of showing edge windows with directly Show procedure (FTop.Show), use show window without activation:

```
ShowWindow(FTop.Handle, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
FTop.Visible := True;
```

[Daniel Rikowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23368/daniel-rikowski) wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/700929/62313)

Comment: Open Task Manager, go to tab *Applications*, right click your untouchable application and select *Switch to*. And that's just one way how to steal focus. Also, only showing the window with `SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE` flag doesn't mean you can't focus the window simply by mouse. [not voting down]

Comment: There are other ways to address those problems, @Tlama. First, these windows strike me as something that would probably be hidden as soon as the program's main window lost focus anyway, so their gaining focus through Task Manager or Explorer is a non-issue. Nonetheless the `ws_ex_NoActivate` window style would make the windows immune to focus by clicking. That window style might even be the answer to this question.

Comment: @Rob, I got the linked question as that OP wants to keep that *highlight rectangle* around the window permanently (until a different window is selected).